# Cannot find my Miniconda Python installation after switching from bash to zsh

Tags: terminal, bash, python, zsh

Recently after upgrading to Catalina, the terminal changed from `bash` to `zsh`, and I lost my Python installation.

My Python was installed with Miniconda, but now I can't find it anymore, I can only see the system default Python.

```
% which -a python
/usr/bin/python
% ipython          
zsh: command not found: ipython
```

How can I find out where my Python installation was and how can I make the `zsh` terminal to use my `conda` Python?

Comment: Run `bash -l` and check for python again. Most probably there are some lines in your .profile or .bashrc which need to be copied into their zsh equivalents

Comment: It reverted the terminal back to `bash` and my Python is working now. My Python was at `/Users/myname/miniconda3/bin/python`.

Comment: So miniconda is still installed. You probably don't want to run `bash` manually each time you need miniconda, so either change the default shell back or copy the relevant lines from .bashrc into .zshrc